# Can additional meta information be automatically stored with DJI-mini-2 images

Tags: dji, photography

When a dji-mini-2 drone makes a photo, is it possible to automatically store the information that the drone clearly knows at the time of snapshot. For example:

- lat/lng of the location
- height of the drone
- angle of the camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mavic Mini, the Mavic, and the Mavic 2 do store these data.  The latitude, longitude, altitude (meters above the WGS84 elipsoid), and azimuth will be written to standard EXIF tags.  The pitch, roll, and, yaw of the drone and the camera gimbal are written to XMP tags.  Depending on your EXIF viewing method you may not be aware of those tags.   Try using [gdalinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html) at the command line, or [EXIFTool](https://exiftool.org/) to view more of the image metadata.   See [this post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-gisp-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-M1gy?utm_source=linkedin_share&utm_medium=member_desktop_web) for more information on exploiting these data.